# How to use Xpath while using apple's UIAutomation to automate apps.?

Tags: ios, automation, ui-automation, hybrid-mobile-app

Iam trying to automate a hybrid app with the [UIAutomation feature](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAScrollViewClassReference/UIAScrollView/UIAScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009912) provided by apple.

Is there any way I can access my DOM elements on the page using Xpath so that i can reach elements using simple class name.

If its not possible with UIAutomation; is there any other way?

Comment: Other way - [Appium](http://appium.io/getting-started.html) based on Selenium WebDriver, you can search for elements using XPath, CSS selectors etc.

Comment: Well; i tried that and yes we can use xpath,css selector. But I have a hybrid app and Iam not able to select the scrollView which Iam able to do using instruments.

Comment: Can you see the element you're looking for in the output of `mainWindow.logElementTree();`?